# CNN regression: output mimic the input test data

Tags: regression, neural-networks, convolution

I am working on convolutional neural network regression problem using U-Net architecture for computing poisson equations. The input data is particle distribution (rho) and the output is electrical potential (phi). After training, i try to predict using arbitrary rho. But why the resulting prediction is mimicking the test input data. What's actually happen? Whereas the MAE and MSE are pretty small (around 0.00xxx).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.